# How to replace query conditions in a loop in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a `user` table with name, status and distance. I want to get the users under a particular `distance` and if the result is empty I want to check it again with an incremented value.

```
    $user = User::where('status',1);

    $i = 10;

    while($i < 50)
    {
        $user->having('distance', '<=', $i);

        if($user->get()->count())
            break;

        $i = $i+5;
    };
```

In the first loop I got the query correctly as `SELECT * from users where status = 1 and having distance <= 10`. If the result is empty in the second loop I got the query as `SELECT * from users where status = 1 and having distance <= 10 and having distance <= 15`. I want to get the query as `SELECT * from users where status = 1 and having distance <= 15`. What change should I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working here on objects and you should use `clone`:

```
$user = User::where('status',1);

$i = 10;

while($i < 50)
{
    $query = (clone $user)->having('distance', '<=', $i);

    if($query->get()->count())
        break;

    $i = $i+5;
}
```

In addition you are using:

```
$query->get()->count()
```

what causes that you get all records matching query from database and calculate their amount. If you just need to have their count, it's much better to use just:

```
$query->count()
```